# Cusps of the modular forms

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, modular-forms, modular-group

[image]

According to the definition of the cusps attached above the set of cusps is infinite and to be more precise it is $Q \cup \infty$ since $G$ is a subgroup of $SL(2,Z)$ so the identity matrix (that is a parabolic element) belongs to $G$ so every point of $Q \cup \infty$ is cusp but they mentioned before that it is finite.

How could this be explained? (In addition, what is cusp?)

Comment: It is finite after modding out by the action of $G$.

Comment: @hunter what do you mean (finite after modding out by the action of $G$?

Comment: From which book/notes this screenshot has taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) i\infty = \Bbb{Q}\cup i\infty$

$SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) i\infty $ is only one point of the modular curve, the one that you need to add to get a compact Riemann surface. The chart is $q\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \frac{\log(q)}{2i\pi}$ for $|q|<1/3$

It works the same way for $\Bbb{Q}\cup i\infty=\bigcup_{j=1}^J G \gamma_j i\infty$ a finite disjoint union, for some $\gamma_j \in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$, and we need to add $J$ points to $G\backslash \Bbb{H}$ to get a compact Riemann surface. The charts are $q\to G \gamma_j k_j\frac{\log(q)}{2i\pi }$ for some $k_j$.

This is what we mean with the cusps of the modular curves.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you didn't mind explaining it to me since I have not got your point.

Comment: I cannot guess what you don't understand.

Comment: The concept of cusp is not clear enough to me, and how it is a finite set (by the definition of cups the set of cusps is $Q \cup \infty$.